# Reformating data with awk command depending on a if condition

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

i have a script that reformated the content of a source file in a target file.
It does it for every files in a directory.

Here is a source file exemple :

```
TABLE;APGFPOLI;
Contrat;CHAR(16);Numéro du contrat
Libelle;CHAR(30);Libellé du contrat
DtCreation;CHAR(8);Date de création
DtMaj;CHAR(8);Date de dernière MAJ
DtEffet;CHAR(8);Date d'effet adhésion
MotifAdh;CHAR(2);Motif d'adhésion
DtRadiation;CHAR(8);Date de radiation
DtEnrRad;CHAR(8);Date enregistrement radiat
MotifRad;CHAR(2);Motif de radiation
MtPrime;Numérique 8.2;Montant prime d'origine
DtEffetSusp;CHAR(8);Date d'effet de suspension
DtFinSusp;CHAR(8);Date de fin de suspension
MotifSusp;CHAR(2);Motif de suspension
DestBord;CHAR(1);Destinataire du bordereau
CdDest;CHAR(5);Code du destinataire
NivRupBord;CHAR(1);Niveau rupture bordereau
BordCETIP;CHAR(1);Bordereau CTIP
EnvBordNom;CHAR(1);Envoi bordereau nominatif
Indice;CHAR(2);Indice appliqué
Echeance;CHAR(2);Echéance de l'indice (MM)
Effectif;CHAR(5);Effectif
CdRegr;CHAR(3);Code regroupement 1
CdGroupe;CHAR(3);Code regroupement 2
Periodicite;CHAR(1);Périodicité
Terme;CHAR(1);Terme
Produit;CHAR(6);Code produit affecté
Inspecteur;CHAR(5);Inspecteur
CleInsp;CHAR(1);Clé inspecteur
Filler;CHAR(6);Filler
```

And here is the target file generated by the shell:

```
01 APGFPOLI.

   * Numéro du contrat.

     05 Contrat PIC X(16).

   * Libellé du contrat.

     05 Libelle PIC X(30).

   * Date de création.

     05 DtCreation PIC X(8).

   * Date de dernière MAJ.

     05 DtMaj PIC X(8).

   * Date d'effet adhésion.

     05 DtEffet PIC X(8).

   * Motif d'adhésion.

     05 MotifAdh PIC X(2).

   * Date de radiation.

     05 DtRadiation PIC X(8).

   * Date enregistrement radiat.

     05 DtEnrRad PIC X(8).

   * Motif de radiation.

     05 MotifRad PIC X(2).

   * Montant prime d'origine.

     05 MtPrime Numérique 8.2.

   * Date d'effet de suspension.

     05 DtEffetSusp PIC X(8).

   * Date de fin de suspension.

     05 DtFinSusp PIC X(8).

   * Motif de suspension.

     05 MotifSusp PIC X(2).

   * Destinataire du bordereau.

     05 DestBord PIC X(1).

   * Code du destinataire.

     05 CdDest PIC X(5).

   * Niveau rupture bordereau.

     05 NivRupBord PIC X(1).

   * Bordereau CTIP.

     05 BordCETIP PIC X(1).

   * Envoi bordereau nominatif.

     05 EnvBordNom PIC X(1).

   * Indice appliqué.

     05 Indice PIC X(2).

   * Echéance de l'indice (MM).

     05 Echeance PIC X(2).

   * Effectif.

     05 Effectif PIC X(5).

   * Code regroupement 1.

     05 CdRegr PIC X(3).

   * Code regroupement 2.

     05 CdGroupe PIC X(3).

   * Périodicité.

     05 Periodicite PIC X(1).

   * Terme.

     05 Terme PIC X(1).

   * Code produit affecté.

     05 Produit PIC X(6).

   * Inspecteur.

     05 Inspecteur PIC X(5).

   * Clé inspecteur.

     05 CleInsp PIC X(1).

   * Filler.

     05 Filler PIC X(6).
```

What i am trying to do is change that line :

```
MtPrime;Numérique 8.2;Montant prime d'origine
```

Like this :

05 MtPrime PIC 9(8).v9(2).

As you can see it changed "Numérique X.Y" by PIC 9(X).v9(Y).

The condition is that if i have only one number "X" after "Numerique" i need to reformat it like this :

"PIC 9(X)"

BUT if i have a number "X" DOT another number "Y" i need to print it like this :

"PIC 9(X).v9(Y)"

Using awk command and being a full beginner i have no clue how can i achieve this.

Here is my shell :

```
#!/bin/bash

SOURCE_DIRECTORY="/home/yha/AG2R/SOURCE/*"
TARGET_DIRECTORY="/home/yha/AG2R/COPY/"

for f in $SOURCE_DIRECTORY 
do 
    b=$(basename "$f")
    echo "Processing $f file.."; 
    awk -F ';' '$1=="TABLE" && $3=="" {printf "01 %s.\n\n", $2; next} {sub(/CHAR/,"PIC X", $2);printf "   * %s.\n\n     05 %s %s.\n\n", $3, $1, $2;}' "$f" > "$TARGET_DIRECTORY/$b.cpy"
done
```

Comment: Did you try to solve this yourself? If yes what did you try and what difficulties did you encounter with it? Else, don't you think it would be better to learn a bit of awk and start trying to solve your programming problems yourself? This would certainly not be a waste of time.

Comment: I tried to do the same thing that i did for the "TABLE" changement but with the word "Numérique". The real problem is more the condition that just changing the original value

Comment: I added this to my awk command : {sub(/Numérique/,"PIC 9", $2);} but having no changes in my output i do not know what i can do to improve it

Comment: Please do not answer in comments. Edit your question, show the exact awk script that you used, show what the output was and explain why it was not correct.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].  Remember we have no clue what you are doing, do not assume anything.  Right now, the code you posted does not produce the target file you show based on the source file exemple.

Answer (score 0):

For the `awk` part, you might use a regex to check for the word followed by a digits and an optional part with a dot and digits.

```
^Numérique [0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$
```

If there is a match, you can split on a space or dot. Then you can assemble the string to print by checking if there is a 3rd entry in the array with splitted values and start the string with the value of the 2nd value.

The data

```
$cat file
TABLE;APGFPOLI;
DtEnrRad;CHAR(8);Date enregistrement radiat
MotifRad;CHAR(2);Motif de radiation
MtPrime;Numérique 8.2;Montant prime d'origine
MtPrime;Numérique 5;Montant prime d'origine
DtEffetSusp;CHAR(8);Date d'effet de suspension
```

awk script

```
awk -F ';' '
$1=="TABLE" && $3=="" {
  printf "01 %s.\n\n", $2;
  next
}
{
  result = $2
  if ($2 ~ /^Numérique [0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$/) {
    nr=split($2,a,"[ .]")
    result = "PIC 9(" a[2] ")"
    if (nr == 3) {
      result = result ".v9(" a[3] ")"
    }    
  }
  sub(/CHAR/,"PIC X", result);
  printf "   * %s.\n\n     05 %s %s.\n\n", $3, $1, result;
}' file
```

Output

```
01 APGFPOLI.

   * Date enregistrement radiat.

     05 DtEnrRad PIC X(8).

   * Motif de radiation.

     05 MotifRad PIC X(2).

   * Montant prime d'origine.

     05 MtPrime PIC 9(8).v9(2).

   * Montant prime d'origine.

     05 MtPrime PIC 9(5).

   * Date d'effet de suspension.

     05 DtEffetSusp PIC X(8).
```